# Why does parallel assignment of a single empty array assign multiple nils?

Tags: ruby, parallel-assignment

I want to assign an empty array to multiple variables. Here is what I'm doing:

```
irb(main):015:0> a, b, c = []
=> []
irb(main):016:0> a
=> nil
irb(main):017:0> b
=> nil
irb(main):018:0> c
=> nil
```

It gives me `nil`. I wonder why? But if I did this:

```
irb(main):019:0> a, b, c = [], [], []
=> [[], [], []]
irb(main):020:0> a
=> []
irb(main):021:0> b
=> []
irb(main):022:0> c
=> []
```

then it works as I expect, but it's a little bit longer than the first one. What's wrong with the first example?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the first one. Ruby is responding correctly. What is it that you claim that is wrong?

Comment: Do you want to multiply the values of the variables (which you surely cannot do with arrays), or do you want multiple variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this example will help you understand the problem:

```
[1] pry(main)> a, b, c = [1,2]
=> [1, 2]
[2] pry(main)> a
=> 1
[3] pry(main)> b
=> 2
[4] pry(main)> c
=> nil
```

Now back to your problem, you are trying to assign the elements in an empty array to variables, as a result, the three variables all get nil value.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = b = c = []
```

but note that all variables will be assigned the **same** array
so:

```
a = b = []
b << 1
p b        # [1]
p a        # [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Parallel Assignment With Single Rvalue

If the assignment contains multiple lvalues and one rvalue, the Ruby attempts to expand the rvalue into an array as if you'd called #to_a on the rvalue. So, the problem with your example of `a, b, c = []` is that it is semantically equivalent to:

```
a, b, c = nil.to_a
```

which would obviously assign nil to the first variable, and leave the others unassigned (which is also nil). In contrast, consider this:

```
a, b, c = 1
a
# => 1
b
# => nil
c
# => nil
```

The same principle is at work, but now you can see that the first lvalue *does* receive an assignment from the right-hand side; it just wasn't obvious when the assignment was nil.

Comment: if so, why `a = nil.to_a #=> []; irb(main):028:0> a # => []`. Why a is equal to [] instead of nil like in my example?

Comment: `which would obviously assign nil to the first variable, and leave the others unassigned (which is also nil). In contrast, consider this:` but "a" gives me nil and not []

Comment: @AlanDert It's not assigning an empty array; it's assigning *the first value of the empty array.*

Answer (score 0):

Ruby destructures arrays when you do parallel assignment:

```
a, b, c = [:foo, :bar, :baz]
a # => :foo
b # => :bar
c # => :baz
```

If you give it an array with too few entries, it sets the remaining values to `nil`:

```
a, b, c = [:foo, :bar]
a # => :foo
b # => :bar
c # => nil
```

So your first example is just the natural extension of this - an empty array definitely has too few entries to assign any of the variables!